# Extract operators and numbers from an equation using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am working on a jQuery calculator which has a live display which will look like this:

```js
let liveDisplayString = $('#liveDisplay').val();
// ex. '42.5*30.6' or '7/2'
```

I am trying to separate out the numbers by the operators `+`, `-`, `*` and `/` and then assign the list items to variables for use in calculation. I also need to grab the operator so I would need another expression to ignore 1-9 and the decimal.

I'm really struggling to understand how to create a regular expression to use in `.match()`.

P.S. I am still very new to programming and the JS language

Comment: You accepted an answer too quickly. The answer you accepted is poor and shows a lack of understanding of the basics of regex. I recommend you use `matchAll` or `exec`, and use capture groups to separate out the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) along with regex to get the job done.

The following extracts the operators `+`, `-`, `*` and `/`.

```js
const value = '42.5*30.6+6-2/6';
const numbers = value.split(/[*]|[+]|[-]|[\/]/);
const operators = value.split(/[^-|+|\/|\*]/).filter(e => e);
console.log(numbers);
console.log(operators);
```

Comment: the operators split doesn't seem to work effectively. The only operator which I seem to be able to pull out is '*' and the '-' operator doesn't split the numbers at all

Comment: @GarrettJH. I've updated the regex. It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing expressions can get quite complicated.

In your case, if an expression is **always** of the form `<value> <operator> <value>` (with or without whitespace), you could split by operator:

```js
const OPERATORS = {
    '*': (a, b) => a * b,
    '/': (a, b) => a * b,
    '+': (a, b) => a * b,
    '-': (a, b) => a * b,
};

function evaluate(input) {
    // Loop over the keys, e.g. '*', '/', ...
    for (const operator in OPERATORS) {
        // Split e.g. '1 + 2' into ['1 ', ' 2']
        // but if the operator is '*' and we have '1+2' we get ['1+2']
        const split = input.split(operator);
        if (split.length === 2) {
            // ^ There was exactly one <operator> in the string
            let [a, b] = split;
            // Trim, e.g. "42.5 " into "42.5" then parse as a float
            a = parseFloat(a.trim());
            b = parseFloat(b.trim());
            // Get the arrow function from OPERATORS and return the call result
            return OPERATORS[operator](a, b);
        }
    }
    throw new Error(`Invalid expression!`);
}

console.log(evaluate('42.5 * 30.6'));
```

If you're new to JS, this might already start to look a bit complicated, and this is just for `<value> <operator> <value>`. If you actually want to start handling e.g. `5 + 2 * 3 + 3`, it's a lot more work.

You could simply parse left-to-right, e.g. `[5, '+', 2, '*', 3, '+', 3]`, but remember the order of operations. You want to evaluate it as `(5 + (2 * 3)) + 3` and not as `((5 + 2) * 3) + 3`. You'll need to use of an algorithm there to "swap" the binary operations properly. But perhaps that's a topic for much later.

---

To actually use RegEx for this, that's also an option:

```js
const input = '42.5 * 30.6';

const match = input.match(/^\s*(\d*\.\d+)\s*(\*|\/|\+|\-)\s*(\d*\.\d+)$/);
// Array destructuring, e.g. [0,1,2,3] results in a=1, op=2, b=3
const [, a, op, b] = match;
console.log('a', a);
console.log('op', op);
console.log('b', b);
```

The RegEx uses `\s*` everywhere to say "there can be whitespace here, but doesn't need to" while `(\d*\.\d+)` allows (decimal) numbers, while `(\*|\/|\+|\-)` wants *a* operator. We need to escape it with `\` because these are all special characters in RegEx.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The first part is definitely way over my head right now, and I couldn't get the implementation down well on the reg exp part, but that may be due to other limitations I've setup in my node server. Thank you for breaking down and explaining what the regexp is trying to do.

Comment: A good site for RegExp is [RegExr](https://regexr.com/). Besides the `Cheatsheet` and `RegEx Reference` in the left sidebar, it allows you to immediately test your RegExp, and even inspect the RegExp itself and the results it produces. I should've mentioned that my RegExp uses capturing groups (wrapping parts in `(...)`) so they can be extracted like e.g. `match[1]`, which I did using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).